# jquery autosuggest using jsonData

Tags: php, jquery, json, autosuggest

I am using jquery autosuggest plugin version: "1.10.3".
I'm dynamically creating an availableTags array in php and converting it onto jsonData.

Now I'm converting more than one such arrays and using a switch statement I'm allowing only a particular set of available Tags in my searchbox.

But my problem is one of my array is not getting displayed in the autosuggest dropdown list of the search box.

Here's my code

```
$query4 = "SELECT `location` FROM `organization` WHERE `approved` = '1'"; 
if($query_run4 = mysql_query($query4))
{
    $resultnames = array();
    $i=0;
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run4))
    {
        $resultnames[$i] = $result['location'];
        $i++;
    }       
    $jsonData4 = json_encode($resultnames);
    //print_r($jsonData4); //It's printing the correct data over here..
}
else
{
    die ("query4 failed!");
}
```

And here's the loadElements function where I have to load the jsonData. Case 4 is where the problem is. All other cases are working perfectly fine.

```
    <script>
        function loadElements(value)
        {
            switch(value)
            {
                case "1":
                var availableTags = <?=$jsonData1 ?>;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
                    });
                break;

                case "2":
                var availableTags = <?=$jsonData2 ?>;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
                });
                break;

                case "3":
                var availableTags = <?=$jsonData3 ?>;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
                });
                break;

                case "4":
                var availableTags = <?=$jsonData4 ?>;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
                });
                break;

                case "5":
                var availableTags = <?=$jsonData5 ?>;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                  source: availableTags
                });
                break;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I'm new to json and jquery and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: how is `loadElements` called?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TkmCZ/1/

Comment: Thank you for replying:)
I'm calling loadElements(value) in <select>


`<select class="textForm" name="selected" required onChange="loadElements(value)">`


Yes the jsfiddle works fine but I don't know, for some reason mine isn't working. Maybe it's because of some default values like 'maxlength' as my 'location' is like 40-50 characters long.

Comment: you need to try to recreate the issue in the fiddle so that we can have a look